# Use javascript to simulate a click event on javascript: href

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I'm using a 3rd party system that allows us to add custom javascript and I need a way to look for a custom URL and then have the system pop up the user login which is called by clicking on  href="javascript:;"

```
< a class="nav-link" href="javascript:;"> < b>sign in</b></ a>
```

Note the class="nav-link" is NOT unique

I have no issue looking for custom URL and doing various actions, but I don't know how to perform a simulated click event on that javascript href so that it pops up the user login.

For instance landing on: "https://our.site.com/webstoreNew/services/guestprofile"
The custom URL portion is "guestprofile" and it doesn't get redirected by main system and stays

I've tried the following:

```
<script>
const guest_url = "https://our.site.com/webstoreNew/services/guestprofile";
let current_url = window.location.href;


if(current_url === guest_url) {

$('href="javascript:;"')[0].click();
}

</script>
```

other things tried:

```
$(javascript:;)[0].click();
$(href="javascript:;")[0].click();
```

I feel like this is probably a syntax issue, but need someone's help

Comment: Is the HTML-part of your question a direct copy of the actual code? If so, the anchor-element is malformed HTML since tags start with "<" immediately followed by the tag-name, with no space inbetween. Same for the closing tag, it starts with "</" immediately followed by the tag-name.

Comment: Sorry.. i had put in spaces, but there are no spaces in the actual code.

<a class="nav-link" href="javascript:;"> <b>sign in</b></a>

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: updated with more of your code and removed code that would work in snippet.

Check my snippet below, just create a function and call it like in my example below `fakeClick();`.

If you want to target the href you mentioned you can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) like this:

```
const href = document.querySelector('[href="javascript:;"]');
```

The snippet below will not trigger a click because we are using `window.location.href;` which isn't supported in stackoverflow snippets. That being said, if you run this in your project it will function as expected.

```js
//your guest url
const guest_url = "https://our.site.com/webstoreNew/services/guestprofile";

let current_url = window.location.href;

//this is the a element where we trigger the click
const href = document.querySelector('[href="javascript:;"]');

console.log(href);


//this is the function
//if both are equal it will trigger a click on atag
function fakeClick() {
if(current_url === guest_url) {

href.click();
}
}

//here we are calling the function so it will run immediately
fakeClick();
```

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="javascript:;"><b>sign in</b></a>
```

Additionally, as @Oskar Grosser mentioned, if you want to use the code from your example you just need to change the incorrect call from this:

```
$('href="javascript:;"')[0].click();
}
```

To this:

```
$('[href="javascript:;"]')[0].click();
}
```

As you can see the adjusted Jquery matches the querySelector call, and should function the same way.

Comment: I think the issue here is "a" element.  In my case there is no such element and it's just a href="javascript:;" reference.

As seen here
< a class="nav-link" href="javascript:;"> < b>sign in</b></ a>

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector - You can use querySelector to find the href. It's a powerful method that can help you reference anything on your page. - Just replace the atag query call with something that can reference your href.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you can target that href.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you query for one or more elements using [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Since you want to query for an exact attribute, you have to format the query-string like this:
`[attributeName="value"]`

Another note is, what you query for has to be in a String. With your other attempts, the browser tries to resolve `javascript` and `href` as if these were variables, hence the errors.

The call of `click()` itself is correct, that will fire a click-event.

```js
// Setup for feedback; ignore
$("a").click(() => console.log("'a' was clicked!"));

// Correct query
$('[href="javascript:;"]').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;">A link</a>
```

Comment: This is great, but for some reason the system is saying this:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at guestprofile:42

I've changed the URL multiple times to see if that's the issue, but no.